# adding SKSpriteNode instances in a loop inside another loop

Tags: ios, loops, sprite-kit, wait, skspritenode

This is my on-going code experimenting in my sandbox app using SpriteKit.

This code is in the GameScene (instance of SKScene). Basically, the code will generate 2 "batches" of throws. First throw will throw 3 stone objects (all 3 objects will appear at the same time) and next throw will be another 2 stone objects (again all 2 objects will appear at the same time). There should be a delay between the first and the second throw.

This is the code but when I run it crashes. If the batch were to be reduced to 1 throw then it works. Also if I suspect it has something to do with the wait delay and adding of the "stone" spritenode but not sure what.

```
for x in 1 ... 2 {

if x == 1 {

intStartIndex = 1
intEndIndex = 3

    } else { 

intStartIndex = 4
intEndIndex = 5

    }

            run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: dblDelay)) {

                for i in intStartIndex ... intEndIndex { 
                    print(i)
                    self.stone[i - 1].position = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: -100)
                    self.stone[i - 1].anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
                    self.stone[i - 1].size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
                    self.stone[i - 1].zPosition = 2
                    self.addChild(self.stone[i - 1])   

                    let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), duration: 0.3)
                    let actionRolling = SKAction.animate(with: stone[i - 1].arrayTexture, timePerFrame: 0.05)
                    let actionSequence = SKAction.sequence([actionMove,actionRolling])
                    stone[i - 1].run(actionSequence)


                }

            }
                dblDelay += 0.5
        }
```

Comment: What's the crash that you see and at what line?

Comment: The crash is at class AppDelegate and message is libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: That means you are probably hitting a nil that shouldnt be nil,  maybe you are getting array out of bounds.

Comment: If i comment out the all the codes except for the print(i) inside of the inner "i" loop, the print statement will print out 4 then 5 then 4 then 5. Not sure why it is repeating  this. I thought it would print 1 then 2 then 3 then delay then 4 then 5.

Comment: no, this is why it is very important to properly align your code. You are using a run action, which fires at a later time.  Well if you look at your code, the completion code is not going to retain the values getting passed in, it is going to use whatever the latest value is saved in your start and end, which is 4 and 5

Comment: If remove the run SKAction.wait, the output will be as per expectation, 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5. But of course there is no delay between the 1 to 3 and 4 to 5. I want this delay. What other ways to implement a delay beside run SKAction.wait?